# How to write an incremental query by steps with sqlite and python?

Tags: python, sqlite, select

I'm new in sqlite and python programming. 
I want to write a select query on a table incrementally with 50 steps ( select  first 50 records, second 50  until the last record based on where clause).

for this porpuse i used '[limit clause](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-limit-clause#targetText=In%20SQLite%20LIMIT%20clause%20is,based%20on%20a%20limit%20value.)' i fetched 50 records. But it just fetches first 50 records.

```
cur.execute(""" SELECT * FROM Log_Table WHERE name= 'x  limit 50 """)
print(cur.fetchall())
```

I want to select records in a for loop with steps of 50 records.
I try it by [range](https://thepythonguru.com/python-builtin-functions/range/#targetText=Python%20range()%20function&targetText=The%20range()%20function%20is%20used,efficient%20to%20handle%20large%20data.&targetText=(optional)%20Starting%20point%20of%20the%20sequence.) function, but it didn't work.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results is a good introduction.

Comment: @Shawn, Thanks. I'l read it

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want `..... LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0` for the first then `LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50` for the next until `LIMIT 50 OFFSET a_number_as_big_or_bigger_than_the_number_of_rows` in which case 0 rows will be returned.

Perhaps consider the following where an additional control table is introduced which could make thing flexible and pretty easy :-

```
/* Just in case the tables exist */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mainTable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iterationControl;

/* The table that will be progressively interrogated */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mainTable(aColumn INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);

/* The control table, could perhaps be TEMP table*/
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS iterationControl (chunkSize INTEGER, chunkStart INTEGER); 
DELETE FROM iterationControl; /* Just in case, clear any rows */
INSERT INTO iterationControl VALUES(50,0,0); /* initialise the iteration table */

/* reset the chunk size for less out for this example only */
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkSize = 5;
/* reset to the start (not needed here but as an example of how to)*/
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = 0;

/* Load some data purely included for testing purposes */
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(val) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT val+1 FROM cte1 LIMIT 10000)
INSERT INTO mainTable SELECT val FROM cte1;

/**START OF TESTING**/
/* First grab */
SELECT * FROM mainTable LIMIT (SELECT chunkSize FROM iterationControl) OFFSET (SELECT chunkStart FROM iterationControl);
/* Post run update*/
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = chunkStart + chunkSize;

/* 2nd grab */
SELECT * FROM mainTable LIMIT (SELECT chunkSize FROM iterationControl) OFFSET (SELECT chunkStart FROM iterationControl);
/* Post run update modified to skip till past the end ONLY FOR EASE OF DEMO */
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = chunkStart + chunkSize + 100000;

/* 3rd grab (mimic last) */
SELECT * FROM mainTable LIMIT (SELECT chunkSize FROM iterationControl) OFFSET (SELECT chunkStart FROM iterationControl);

/* Reset iteration Control to start from the begining*/
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = 0;
/* First of a new set of grabs */
SELECT * FROM mainTable LIMIT (SELECT chunkSize FROM iterationControl) OFFSET (SELECT chunkStart FROM iterationControl);
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = chunkStart + chunkSize;

/* change size of data part way through from 5 to 13 rows per grab */
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkSize = 13;
/* 2nd grab now at 13 per grab */
SELECT * FROM mainTable LIMIT (SELECT chunkSize FROM iterationControl) OFFSET (SELECT chunkStart FROM iterationControl);
/* no change to post run even though different grab size */
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = chunkStart + chunkSize;

/* 3rd grab (just to show that post update worked correctly) */
SELECT * FROM mainTable LIMIT (SELECT chunkSize FROM iterationControl) OFFSET (SELECT chunkStart FROM iterationControl);
UPDATE iterationControl SET chunkStart = chunkStart + chunkSize;


/* clean up the database as I do not want these tables hanging around */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mainTable;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS iterationControl;
```

## Results

The results from the above being

### 1. Very first grab (5 rows as per control)

[image]

### 2. 2nd Grab (next 5)

[image]

### 3. Last Grab (no rows as past the end (in this case way past))

[image]

### 4. After resetting to start (first grab again)

[image]

### 5. After on the fly change to grab/chuck size (from 5 to 13)

[image]

### 6. Another grab of 13, just to confirm exactly the same post update works correctly

[image]

Comment: Thanks MikeT. I will try it. I use python to select and update a table.